# Loop through list of URLs and scrape tspan elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering if there is a way to loop through a list of URLs, and from each one, import HTML elements named 'tspan'.

How can I do that?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) python libraries, Requests allow you to pull all the html code and then bs4 can be used to look for the specific content in the code you want.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It makes it difficult for people to copy and paste your code to try and run it or post answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup`  if you've already downloaded the `html` source of the page. Otherwise, make use of `urllib.request.urlopen` to get the page's source.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """
<div>
    <g transform="translate(-128.8249969482422,-7.941666603088379)"> 
        <text text-anchor="left" style="; fill:#000;"> 
            <tspan dy="1em" </tspan> 
    </text> 
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-128.8249969482422,-7.941666603088379)"> 
        <text text-anchor="left" style="; fill:#000;"> 
            <tspan dy="1em" 2</tspan> 
    </text> 
    </g>
</div>"""

soup = bs(html)

tspans = soup.find_all("tspan")
tspans
[<tspan dy="1em" x="1"></tspan>,
 <tspan dy="1em" x="1"></tspan>]

texts = [tspan.text for tspan in tspans]
texts
```